# What are the best practices to model database records as javascript class objects?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am looking for a guide on how to initialize a javascript class based on a database record. For example, suppose I have a User model. Therefore, I would have a User class that 1) creates and saves a new user to the database and 2) retrieves the user and initializes it. The class that I am thinking of would look like this:

```
 class User {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  static createUser(user) {
    // makes a call to an API to store the user in a database
  }

  static fromDB(user) {
   // user comes from a database call
   this.user = user;
  }

 sayHello() {
   console.log('hi!');
 }
}
```

Use case 1 - store user in db:

```
User.createUser(user);
```

Use case 2 - initiate new user object

```
const userRecord = APICallToDbToGetUser()
const user = new User(User.fromDb(userRecord));
user.sayHello();
```

I wasn't sure if this was the best practice or not and could not find tutorials on the subject. Any feedback on this would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `userInstance.user = user`? Don't. Give your `User` class the attributes that a user should have.

Comment: Just have `user = User.fromDb(userRecord)`, where `fromDb` already returns a `new User`.